# Intellij-idea: Using Eclipse Keymap on Mac OS X

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

When using IntelliJ with the Eclipse Keymap, all the shortcuts are set to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, instead of <kbd>Command</kbd>. Just like Eclipse on Windows.

Is there a way to use the same keys as the Mac version of Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

This was actually already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9115464/223855. You can find a link to an "Eclipse on Mac" keymap xml file there.

Answer (score 1):

If you go Preferences->(IDE Settings) Keymap, from here you should see a drop down for Keymaps which will allow you to select "Mac OS X" to switch over to using Command instead.  At least this is an option for IntelliJ 11.1.2.

Comment: This is not the same as the keymap of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a copy of the Ecplipse key map (in IDEA) then exit IDEA. 
Then modify the newly created xml file in your config\keymaps directory with search replace in a text editor replacing "control" whatever Command's text string is, "command"? (I don't have a mac).

You can get commands text by modifying one keystroke in the copied keymap to use command.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got it installed but just don't know it. There is a trick to this.

In IntelliJ Preferences, Under Keymap: Click the dropdown Menu. Secretly, JetBrains designed it as a scrolling menu which lacks a scroll bar until you actually scroll it (deceptive). Hover your mouse over the menu and scroll it down to find an Eclipse (Mac) variant, among others. On my Mac, i cannot even use my keyboard to scroll this menu, it must be the mouse.

[Scrollable Keymap List Has More Options Underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Z9K.jpg)